# How to create linear projection plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I would like to create plot similar to this one from orange: [image]
I have a 3 class classification problem and I would like to plot each sample based on the probabilities of belonging to each class. I can do multiple pairwise scatterplots, but that is suboptimal.

This question is not a duplicate of PCA biplot questions suggested bellow/above. I am not asking how to do PCA and create plots based on PC and show loadings as arrows, I am asking how to project and plot something, in a way that all the loadings arrows would be in a same angle from each other, as is in the plot above.

Comment: There is also base solution at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/what-are-the-four-axes-on-pca-biplot

Comment: library scatter3D did what I wanted. Solution is basically scatter3D(x, y, z) and there are more graphical options and examples in http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization